# Any digital permutation

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, open-ended-function

## Task

Your task is to output a single integer, with one restriction: its digits must be a permutation of [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6].

For example, you could output 653443653152432, 413265345463352, or any of the other 15-digit integers whose digits are a permutation of the list.

## Rules

- Your code must terminate in a reasonable amount of time (do not just enumerate every integer until you get to 122333344455566).
- If your language doesn't support 15-digit integers, or if there is no meaningful distinction between strings and integers in your language, you may output a string.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: What's to stop me simply outputting 653443653152432?

Comment: Because you could do it in fewer bytes than just writing out the integer.

Comment: Would be more interesting if we had to a random one of all the permutations, with equal chance for each.

Comment: "Reasonable amount of time" tha'ts pretty vague, you need to set a limit.  Even seomthing like 30 seconds or 15 works.

Comment: If we output to STDOUT (or STDERR) then there surely is no difference between printing a string or a number, no?

Comment: Is there any reason that particular set of digits was chosen? Or is it arbitrary?

Comment: [Reminder: Don't upvote trivial answers.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-can-we-help-users-who-are-put-off-by-the-use-of-golfing-languages/10132#10132)  Upvote if somebody solves this in, say, boolfuck.

Comment: I suspect that you found some short expression that gives a number with the right digits before posting this. I'd suggest against such puzzles. It's more about finding the expression you had in mind that golfing code, and once someone has the expression, probably everyone can copy it into other languages.

Comment: @xnor I personally think that this challenge is underrated. If I did my math correctly, there are 378,378,000 possible outcomes. Even if the OP found a terse expression for _one_ of them, it is quite possible that a shorter one exists for another permutation.

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```js
let f =

_=>266**6+19

console.log(f())
```

This computes: **266<sup>6</sup> + 19 = 354233654641216 + 19 = 354233654641235**

There are two triples **(a, b, c)** with **0 < a < 1000**, **0 < b < 10**, **0 < c < 100** and **a<sup>b</sup> + c** satisfying the condition.

The following snippet finds them almost instantly.

```js
for(a = 1; a < 1000; a++) {
  for(b = 1; b < 10; b++) {
    for(c = 1; c < 100; c++) {
      if((r = a**b + c + '').match(/^[1-6]+$/) && [...r].sort().join`` == '122333344455566') {
        console.log(a + '**' + b + ' + ' + c + ' = ' + r);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tcl sucks using your approach: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6taKgSMHIzExLy0zb0DL2/38A

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 65 bytes

```
(((((((((((((((((((()()()){}){}){}){}())()))()))))())))())))()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwML0ARBzepaOALygAiMoSSc@P//v64jAA)

This is `64` bytes of source code and `+1` for the `-A` flag. This simply pushes the ASCII values of each digit in a row. For reference, pushing the number `122333344455566` would take 238 bytes:

```
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()()()){}){}){})()){}{}){({}[()])}{}){}){}())){}{})){}{}){}())){}{})()){}{})){}{}){}())){}{}){}())){}{}){}())()){}{})()){}{})){}{})()){}{})()){}{})){}{}){}())){}{}){}())){}{})){}{}){}()){})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X4NkoAmCmtW1UARmg5ga1bXRGpqxmrUwKaAMRAqqACGggUsCnamBVYMGCcYgCQDp//8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>12</s>, 10 bytes

```
2¬26¬35a13
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3@jQGiOzQ2uMTRMNjf//BwA)

This generates the range `[2, 6]` twice, then the range `[3, 5]`, and then appends `13`.

Outputs:

```
234562345634513
```

Answer (score 2):

## Turing machine, <s>132</s> 122 bytes

...and <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>8</s> 7 states, including `halt`.

```
0 _ x r A
0 x y r A
0 y z r A
0 z _ r C
0 * * l 0
A _ 6 r B
A * * r A
B _ 2 r C
C * 3 r D
D _ 4 r E
D 2 1 l halt
E _ 5 l 0
```

[Here is a Turing machine simulator that understands this syntax.](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html) You should paste the code, clear the "Initial input" field, press Reset, then press Run.

### How it works

Outputs `313456234562345` by looping to write `62345` three times and then writing `31` on top of the initial `62`.

---

*-10 bytes thanks to @Leo*

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
“|BS½GA’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5wap@BDe90dHzXM/P8fAA)

Simply a base-250 compressed version of the number `122333344455566`

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Mr. Xcoder

Comment: 8 bytes: `“|BS½GA’`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder why didn't I try that one first? :P Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
↓čvν□⅟“
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMTkzJXUwMTBEdiV1MDNCRCV1MjVBMSV1MjE1RiV1MjAxQw__)
A simple compressed number.

Alternate 9 byte run-length version:

```
Ƨ≡+‰“7─◄H
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwMUE3JXUyMjYxKyV1MjAzMCV1MjAxQzcldTI1MDAldTI1QzRI)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 40 bytes

```
+++++++[>+++++++<-]>.+..+....+...+...+..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwKi7aAMG91YOz1tPRCCEFD8/z8A)

fairly boring solution

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
•=["∊…Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcMi22ilRx1djxqWBf7/DwA)

Comment: `1243ƶ` would've been cool if there were 5 and 6 times a number.

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge-93, <s>16</s> 14 or 12 bytes

The only native integer literals supported by Befunge are the numbers 0 to 9, so coming up with an efficient representation for larger values is actually quite a common problem. In this case, though, it's not just a matter of finding the most efficient representation for a number, but also choosing a target number whose best representation is the shortest of all possible targets.

After trying thousands of different combinations, the best I've been able to do so far is 14 bytes (12 to calculate the number, and then two more bytes to output it).

```
m&"7*:*::**+.@
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=bSYiNyo6Kjo6KiorLkA&input=)

If we allow extended ASCII characters, though, we can improve on the above solution by two bytes with:

```
eûãÃ"**:*+.@
```

This is using the Latin-1 encoding, which we unfortunately can't demonstrate on TIO, since it doesn't support 8-byte encodings for the Befunge interpreters.

**Explanation**

In the first answer, we start with the string `"m&"`, which essentially pushes the values 109 and 38 onto the stack. Note that we save a byte by dropping the opening quote, since we can rely on Befunge's wrap-around playfield to have the one quote both open and close the string (this pushes a number of additional values onto the stack that we don't need, but we only care about the final two).

We then push an additional `7` onto the stack, and execute the sequence `*:*::**+`, which performs a set of arithmetic calculations with the stack values, essentially calculating the expression:

```
109+(38*7)^2^3 = 354233654641325
```

Finally we use the `.` instruction to output the result of the calculation, and then the `@` instruction ends the program.

In the second answer, we start with the string `"eûãÃ"`, which pushes the values 101, 251, 227 and 195. We then execute the sequence `**:*+`, which performs the required calculations on those values:

```
101+(251*227*195)^2 = 123443543565326
```

And again we finish with the instructions `.` and `@` to output the result and exit.

Note that in both cases you need to be using an interpreter which supports 64-bit integers. Also note that the string wrapping trick won't work on Befunge-98 interpreters, since it relies on the interpreter ignoring instructions it doesn't recognise, but in Befunge-98 an invalid instruction will reflect.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
»Ċ¨?»²›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCu8SKwqg/wrvCsuKAuiIsIiIsIiJd)
Port of the second answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247594/107262)
Explanation:

```
»Ċ¨?»   # Compressed integer 11972312
     ²  # Squared
      › # Increment
```

I was on my way to making a super short one but I had read the rules wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 21 bytes

```python
print 122333344455566
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EwdDIyBgITExMTE1Nzcz@/wcA)

Comment: `print 0x6f42f38a5b8e`

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
4967b5Ėẋ/€FḌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/E0sw8yfTItIe7uvUfNa1xe7ij5/9/AA)

could probably be shorter

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 9 bytes

```
."16U<³
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.%2216%16U%C2%82%3C%C2%B3&debug=0)**

**Output:**

```
223133344455566
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 89 bytes

```
proc f a\ b {expr rand()>.5}
puts [join [lsort -command f [split 122333344455566 ""]] ""]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFNITFGIUmhOrWioEihKDEvRUPTTs@0lqugtKRYITorPzNPITqnOL@oREE3OT83F6gAqCW6uCAns0TB0MjIGAhMTExMTU3NzBSUlGJjQcT//wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 20 bytes

```
puts 122333344455566
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWMHQyMgYCExMTExNTc3M/v8HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 20 bytes

```
"ek,@122333344455566
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/Xyk1W8fB0MjIGAhMTExMTU3NzP7/BwA)

Output is `665554443333221`.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 23 bytes

```
{"233456"​​​​​*2+145​}​
```

Outputs: 233456233456145

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/74163)

```apl
⎕pp←30
37+266*6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBI/6phYUPGqbYGzAZWyubWRmpmUGAA)

Used @Arnauld's snippet, so credit goes to them.

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 24 bytes

```cpp
[]{return(57LL<<41)-31;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv6fWFqSr5CmYPs/Ora6KLWktChPw9Tcx8fGxsRQU9fY0Lr2vzUXl3JmXnJOaUqqgk1mfnFJUWpirh1XZl6JQm5iZp6GpkJ1cUmKlVVyfmmJgo2NQpqGJlAXAA)

Returns 57×2<sup>41</sup>−31 = 125344325566433.

Answer (score 0):

## ARM T32 machine code, 8 bytes

```
20d5 f24e 6157 4770
```

Following the [AAPCS](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/aapcs32/aapcs32.rst), this is a function returning a 64-bit integer in r0 and r1. The number is 58967×2<sup>32</sup>+213=253261336543445.

Disassembled:

```
20d5        movs    r0, #213
f24e 6157   movw    r1, #58967
4770        bx  lr
```

Answer (score 0):

## [A0A0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A0A0), 16 bytes

```
O122333344455566
```

`O` outputs the number after it. The number after it is a valid integer.

I don't really think it's possible to save bytes by using some arithmetic expression. When multiplying two numbers of n and m digits, the resulting length of the multiplication will be at most n + m. Doing such a multiplication requires at least n + m + 2 (ignoring the operand) bytes, at which point you might as well just write the result directly. Addition is even worse in terms of length. Considering multiplication, addition and subtraction are the only built-in operators I find it hard to believe this can be shortened. I'd love to be proven wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 9 bytes

```
6A 85 58 BA 4F C9 00 00 C3
```

Returns a 64-bit integer in EDX and EAX, as is standard. The value is 51536×2<sup>32</sup>−123 = 221345434566533.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZA/T8MwFMTn@FNcgyrZbVK1ibI0hIWZhYmBxfhPYsmxrTgplRBfneAisSCWk97de7@Tnih7IdaVxxH0Oafk0Fv/xi000ecsLHFAearqFsEHKH4l2egvUPJaoDk1dUOySc2E5awlxHrX40eMm6HpxRt58@@ME3aRCvdxlsYfhgdyWxi5cZSRD5KFKc2a5ltrzat74mIwTkF4qc55oSlLkEx4F2csLpreKQkx8Am7gA7034Tp9o8lEkR6/HZhe6xe8gKi24X9nrV4H4xViYZNh@P1sU6ln@v6JbTlfVzLsa6SpDd16V7Zbw)

In assembly:

```
f:  push -123; pop eax
    mov edx, 51535
    ret
```

---

Some alternatives that also take 9 bytes:

---

```
B8 D8 AE B6 00 F7 E0 40 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVC7TsQwEKztr1iMTrLvcqdLUiAuhIaahoqCxqztxNLGjvI4TkL8OsEB0SCa0e7M7Iy0uG8Ql0WPHcgnIfmhofiqCRx3J9bFM1h9ySDPb2@KMi8462ZaKc58wJ9hsBNXQlWcUwwNfIMPEzh5jt6s/HXy0mws3I2T8fHQ3vPV0GkfpOLvnPVD2p0UGyL/Eh41tj5YwGjsSWROqhTCMIZxgjmMvgnWALZ6gG0PNch/FeWqPxSmEBPhtws2x@JZZID1tt/tVAVvrSeb0uCqhuPloUylH8vyiY50My77riwSpD/V6d7SFw)

```
f:  mov eax, 11972312
    mul eax
    inc eax
    ret
```

11972312<sup>2</sup>+1 = 143336254625343

---

```
6A E1 58 0F B6 D4 B6 71 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZA7T8MwFIXn@FecBlWy26Rqmq0hLMwsTAwsxo/YkmNbeZQIxF8nuJVYEMuRzrn3fke6ouyEWFc@9qDPOSWHzoU37qCJPmdxHg3KumoQQ4TiC8n6cPlYoORSgJubhTQFqqom2aAmwnLWEOKC73AT6ydoeglWXvM764WbpcL9OEkbDuaBXBd6bj1l5JNkcUhe03zrnH31T1wY6xVEkOqcF5qyBMlE8OOE2Y@280pCGD5gF9GC/jthuvkTiQSRAb9d2B5PL3kB0e7ifs8avBvrVKJh0@K4PNap9Gtdv4V2vBvXsq9PSdLH2nSv3A8)

```
f:  push -31; pop eax
    movzx edx, ah
    mov dh, 113
    ret
```

114×2<sup>40</sup>−31 = 125344325566433